# Visual studio vb.net intellisence auto create function ()

Tags: vb.net, autocomplete, intellisense

In visual studio programming in Vb.Net you get a special autocomplete around functions.

If you add a name in front of a statement the rest of the line is treated like function parameters.

```
strInEditBy  dsInfo.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("plandesc").ToString()

strInEditBy ( dsInfo.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("plandesc").ToString() )
```

I wanted to add a = operator in the place of the ( but unless I type really fast it auto-adds the ( ).

How can I turn that off.

Comment: You should add a `Visual-Studio-YourVersion` Tag to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could turn off the `Pretty Listing (reformatting) of code`.

[MSDN: VB Specific, Basic, Text Editor, Options Dialog Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0y5th94.aspx)

Comment: This seems to work. I'll check if it leads to any wanted 'intellisense' missing.